Cant call Another Composable function inside the onClick parameter of Card which is inside another Composable
so i have made one alert dialog inside a  EnterAlertDialog composable function  and when the card is clicked then inside the onClick parameter of the Card which is in AmlanCard Composable i need to call EnterAlertDialog but i am getting this error :  @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
AmlanCard Composable
EnterAlertDialog Composable
the only thing i know is that onclick

Update some state from onClick that will cause your dialog to appear. In the example in the documentation, you would update openAlertDialog to true to show the dialog.
